# Input of euclidean layer of Caffe must be 2dims?

Tags: caffe

I tried with input of `B*C*H*W`, it seems that the result is no difference with input of `B*(C*H*W)`.

So, is `Flatten` the must do action before `euclidean`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way caffe is computing the [loss](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cpp): as long as the `count` of both inputs is the same (that is, both `bottom`s has the same number of elements) the shape into which these elements are arranged into does not matter.